# How to render a browser in Docusaurus

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

I am trying to render a browser, as shown in Docusaurus guide:
[image]

- Should the file be `file-name.mdx` instead of `.md`? (I tried it, didn't help.)
- I tried to copy the code from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/docusaurus/master/website/docs/markdown-features.mdx), but no luck. Can anyone help. It's pretty new framework and I couldn't find any solution on internet. Any captain for rescue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it after going through their github a little.
You need to have style components for such styling.

I copied the `/src/components/BrowserWindow` contents from docusaurus' [github](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/tree/master/website/src/components/BrowserWindow).

Not sure if there is any easier way to just generate/build it in my workspace.

Comment: Nope not at the moment. We didn't export it as a common component. Your way is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this on your page, you need to do the following:

**Download `BrowserWindow` component**

First, you need two extra files:

- https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/website/src/components/BrowserWindow/index.tsx
- https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/website/src/components/BrowserWindow/styles.module.css

from Docusaurus github.

Copy/past these files in the appropriate folder of your repo:

```bash
<root-your-repo>/src/components/BrowserWindow
```

**Create `.mdx` file**

> MDX Docusaurus has built-in support for MDX, which allows you to write JSX within your Markdown files and render them as React components.

Then you need to create `file.mdx` and put the following in it:

```
import BrowserWindow from '@site/src/components/BrowserWindow';

<BrowserWindow>
    <img src="https://github.com/Ajay-Dhangar.png" width="150" /> <br />
    <button onClick={() => alert('Hello, world!')}>Click Me</button>
 </BrowserWindow>
```

**Run dev server**

After rerun your development server:

```bash
npm run start
```

and by pressing F5 key once (clear your browser cache) this will render in the browser as follows:

[image]

### Improvement

I made a small improvement. And if you run this:

**You'll get this:**

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

You Can also Created with the help of **HTML**, and **CSS**

```css
.browserWindow {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.browserWindowHeader {
  align-items: center;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.buttons {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.browserWindowAddressBar {
  flex: 1 0;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font: 400 13px Arial, sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
}

.dot {
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.browserWindowMenuIcon {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.bar {
  width: 17px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 3px 0;
  display: block;
}

.browserWindowBody {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
  border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.browserWindowBody *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Browser Window</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./window.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="browserWindow" style="min-height: 400px;">
    <div class="browserWindowHeader">
      <div class="buttons">
        <span class="dot" style="background: #f25f58;"></span>
        <span class="dot" style="background: #fbbe3c;"></span>
        <span class="dot" style="background: #58cb42;"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="browserWindowAddressBar text--truncate">
        http://localhost:3000
      </div>
      <div class="browserWindowMenuIcon">
        <div>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="browserWindowBody">
      <!-- Your content goes here -->
      <h1>
        Hi there! I'm a browser window. 
      </h1>
      <p>
        Created by <a href="https://github.com/Ajay-Dhangar" target="_blank">Ajay Dhangar</a>
       </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```